# Error al acceder a mi web desde el xampp

Tags: xampp

Tengo instalado el xampp, y cuando pongo `localhost` me muestra la pagina por defecto del apache.
Cuando trato de entrar a mi pagina web dice que no encontró mi pagina, que no existe.

La ruta que pongo en el buscador es: `localhost/proyecto/index.html` y el proyecto lo tengo guardado dentro de: `xampp/htdocs`.

Alguna idea?

Comment: Es una pregunta tonta... pero te fijaste que este bien escrito?? seria bueno que verifiques el directorio de archivos, tal vez el problema sea una simple letra en el nombre de tus archivos o la ruta donde esta alojada.

Comment: si lo he comprobado varias veces y nada,es bastante extraño jeje

Comment: solo entra a *localhost/proyecto* para verificar que por defecto te lleve al index

Comment: no hace nada, dice que no lo encuentra, pero localhost solo si lo muestra

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta agregando el código de tu archivo index por favor?

Comment: lo que me parece raro es que segun vos, ni siquiera encuentra el directorio *proyecto*... ademas del codigo que piden tambien seria bueno que nos muestres la estructura de archivos desde la consola... has un dir en la ruta del htdocs y despues en el directorio proyecto

Comment: Probá haciendo la siguiente prueba, crea un archivo `index.php` en una nueva carpeta `xampp/htdocs/test/` y poné simplemente un código simple de `html`, luego dirigite a `localhost/test` y chequeá si te funciona.

Comment: Otra cosa, decís que lo estás guardando en `xampp/htdocs` pero debería ser en `xampp/htdocs/proyecto/` ¿Es ahí dónde está o simplemente lo escribiste mal en la pregunta?